# Call Views from Xml class in anothern new class

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater

I am new android/java student
i try to make Test App
But i faced  problem and searched for it but not solved
I made a new xml file (new screen for the app) and i want to use xml elements in the new java class.

After search tried to use Inflator but not working
no error but not return the desired value.
Please help.

*Main Class.java

```
package online.pharmastars.dosecalculator;

            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Spinner;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.drug_spinner);
                    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                            R.array.drugs_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                String selectedDrug = "";
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
                    selectedDrug = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // Another interface callback
                }

                public void calculateDose(View view){
                    Intent doseCalculate = new Intent(this, DoseCalculation.class);
                    startActivity(doseCalculate);
                }
            }
```

And The new class.java is :

package online.pharmastars.dosecalculator;

```
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TextView;

            import static online.pharmastars.dosecalculator.R.id.weight;

            /**
             * Created by ahmed on 4/24/2017.
             */

            public class DoseCalculation extends AppCompatActivity {
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.dose_calculation);
                    calculateDose();
                }

                public void calculateDose(){
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                    EditText pWeight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.age_years);
                    String test = pWeight.getText().toString();
                    TextView patientWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_weight);
                    patientWeight.setText(test);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to use [Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for this

Comment: I think you forgot to set the view. Where do you want this `R.layout.activity_main` view? in first activity? or in second one? And why do we need a separate class for viewing the same view? Can achieve within same class(the first class itself.)

Comment: Do you want to switch from one activity to another?

Comment: yes iwant to switch from one class to another

Comment: when you click button on the first screen .. open new screen with different layout

Comment: for declaration
i have 2 layout files with 2 classes
i need to access the view of main layoutxml from the new class

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to call the method whick opens new activity in your onCreate method

```
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.drug_spinner);
                // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.drugs_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                calculateDose();

            }
```

and modify your method like this

```
 public void calculateDose(View view){
                    Intent doseCalculate = new Intent(this, DoseCalculation.class);
                    startActivity(doseCalculate);
                }
```

and in calculateDose method there is no need for argument `View`

Comment: for declaration i have 2 layout files with 2 classes i need to access the view of main layoutxml from the new class

Comment: the new activity starts no problem but i want to get the edit text for example from the main activity to use its value in the new activity

Comment: did you call the function in onCreate Method?

Comment: i have no error
but the value of editText doesn't appera in the new TextView
like ..
enter ur age = 15 this is the edittext
and in the new layout must appear like your age = 15
but it come blank like your age = (blank)

Comment: That's because you haven't pass the value to the next page